# Mobile post page - next post fly out vs. static next post

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, layout, mobile-web

I am working on a heavy content site. 
On desktop post page i have sticky sidebar that displays the next posts.

On mobile at the bottom of the page when the post is over, the read next stories are following the share buttons.

The client wants to have a flyout post at the bottom to prompt the user to click. My concern is that this never work well on mobile and that the experience will be compromised if the user will be about to share an article and then that thing will fly out, or if he will want to keep scrolling and read the articles that are at the bottom.

So i would like to say no on that but maybe there are other options i can do on mobile, Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can display next post fly box only after the user scroll enough, maybe with a few seconds delay after he rich the bottom of the page. 
I don't think the post will affect the share. Some website have the share buttons on the top.

The box can disappear again if the user keeps scrolling to read the articles that are at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Flyout elements can be distracting. If it has to happen you can consider just sliding it out from bottom to top but make sure it doesn't cover the sharing options.

While the real estate is limited, one alternative is to also have a sticky section on mobile (it'll be consistent with web experience). Perhaps at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I ended up having a sticky strip at the bottom of the page that comes up after a certain height... 

Comment: Sounds good, glad it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose convincing the client is important and believe me, I have only been able to do that by making a prototype, conducting quick usability test with friends, record the usage and prove that it's not working.

This technique almost always works. The worst case, you might not see any problem at all, which means even the sticky works without issues, even then, you would've just learn a new thing

You could use a prototyping tool like "Principle" or "Framer" to quickly make a testable prototype.